# Firebase Swift String Error childByAppendingPath

Tags: swift, firebase

Using the samples provided for Swift from:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/understanding-data.html

I am attempting to retrieve data following this example and display the values in a label control.

Here's what I have:

```
@IBOutlet weak var lblUser: UILabel!

.....

var myRootRef = Firebase(url:"https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/web/data")

lblUser.text = myRootRef.childByAppendingPath("users/mchen/name")
```

I receive an error

> cannot assign a value of type Firebase to a value of type string

I get different errors by attempting to add `as? String`.

What am I missing?

Comment: The guide doesn't cover retrieving a value until step 4. The childByAppendingPath method you call return a reference to a location in the Firebase database, which is of type Firebase. You're trying to assign it to a string, hence the error message.

Comment: Oh, so if I gather correctly, an observer is required to retrieve data, no matter if it's a single instance or watching data for changes.  Either way to get data I must register an observeEventType?  I believed, likely due to jumping around the docs, "observers" were more for monitoring.  Thank you!

Comment: Firebase's data model is entirely built around monitoring data paths for changes. If not anything else, take 2 minutes and read step 5 of the Firebase quickstart for iOS: https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/quickstart.html

Comment: Better yet, read the entire guide and save yourself a dozen hours of thrashing.

Comment: Indeed, working on that.  Bit of tunnel vision due to this project.  Although Guide Section 2 at first does somewhat suggest the code would return "Mary Chen" in Swift.  Thrashing already taking place after figuring out typecasting, now onto async issues...

Answer (score 0):

While retrieving data from Firebase database, you need to write the code as below:

```
        var ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/web/data/")
        ref.child("users").child("mchen").child("name")           
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let name = snapshot.value as? String {
                lblUser.text = name
            }
        })
```